# From where to learn Apache OFBiz components?

Tags: ofbiz

I am new to OFBiz and trying to learn that.

I went through custom development , creating custom entity- services-events and one practice CRUD , I got little bit idea about how screens render and how the flow goes in OFBiz. 
But ahead, for using OFBiz , i need to understand which type of facility available with different components. Without knowing the full functionality of component, how can i use that component ? 
So how can i get information for what the functionality of different component provide ? Or i have to go through that for looking in of that code.

I googled it but can't find any helpful tutorial for at least basic functionality of components/applications in OFBiz

Thanks, 
Ankit

Answer (score 1):

Each OFBiz component is build around group of entities/business domain, which roughly correspods to a chapter from Data Model Resource Book [vol 1](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0471380237/?tag=hydra0b-21&hvadid=9550933629&ref=asc_df_0471380237). I think reading that book will help you understand how the component is supposed to work

Answer (score 0):

Here are several books community recommends:
https://cwiki.apache.org/OFBADMIN/ofbiz-related-books.html.

"Apache OFBiz Development: The Beginner's Tutorial ." is the one I have read. Although it's a little old (based on ofbiz 4.0), but it's not obsoleted since much essential part of ofbiz does not change a lot.